# Amazon SES and Amavis

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, amavis, amazon-ses

I've been following [how to set up a mail server](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/index.html) - by Flurdy in order to set up a more secure mail server on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 instance. I've followed the article to the letter, but I can't get it working alongside Amazon SES.

Amazon SES has been set up for Postfix following this [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html)

```
#Amavis configuration:
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

#SES configuration:
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

With the Amavis `content_filter` uncommented the mail logs reveal deferred

```
>> postfix/smtp[6534]: 0C1084605: to=<xxxxx@xxx.com, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=35, delays=35/0.03/0/0, dsn=4.7.4, status=deferred (TLS is required, but was not offered by host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1])
```

However when `content_filter` is commented out - the relay is set to Amazon SES - and emails are sent fine..

```
>> postfix/smtp[6697]: 333744B3B: to=<xxxxx@xxx.com>, relay=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[54.243.161.229]:25, delay=19, delays=17/0/0.8/0.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 0000013e5a87e718-87720c2b-5542-4e3d-8034-57f3152e2e05-000000)
```

Can anyone shed some light? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

with `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt` you force postfix to use TLS, even through your local amavis filter which might not support it

you could  add `-o smtp_tls_security_level=none` to the amavis/reinject instance in `master.cf` to get this working

so, copying from from your how-to page, your master.cf should probably look like this:

```
amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp 
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200 
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes 
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes 
  -o max_use=20
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none        <----- add this line



 127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd 
  -o content_filter= 
  -o local_recipient_maps= 
  -o relay_recipient_maps= 
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes= 
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no 
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject 
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= 
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= 
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject 
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining 
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions= 
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8 
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0 
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001 
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000 
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0 
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0 
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none    <----- add this line
```